# How to use custom PHP templated system

Tags: php

We are building an app and would like to separate html part from code(php) part, how can we use following template file with php?

```
<h1>{$heading}</h1>
<p>{$content}</>
```

And php code as following...

```
<?php
$heading = $row['heading'];
$description = $row['content'];
?>
```

how can we inlclude tpl file and use it? thanks.

Comment: Why not use something tested and pre-existing such as Twig http://www.twig-project.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, that's unusable templating system.

Imagine there will be 20 headings and 20 descriptions on the page? Gonna write them all? And then HTML got changed and you'll have to change it 20 times? There is no benefit in such template.

In fact, **there is not a single reason in separating HTML from PHP**.

It's **business logic** should be separated from **presentation logic**, as you'll have to use some logic in your template anyway. And PHP is as good for this as any other *templating* language.

Just separate your code into 2 parts: getting data part and displaying part.

Make your regular PHP page get all required data, then define a template for this data and then call main site template, which will render whole page.

Well, here is a rough example of such separation.
Imagine you have `links.php` page contains links to friendly sites. this page should get all required data and then call a template:

```
<?
//include our settings, connect to database etc.
include dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/cfg/settings.php';
//getting required data
$DATA=dbgetarr("SELECT * FROM links");
$pagetitle = "Links to friend sites";
//etc
//and then call a template:
$tpl = "links.tpl.php";
include "main.tpl.php";
?>
```

where `main.tpl.php` is your main site template, including common parts, like header, footer, menu etc:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>My site. <?=$pagetitle?></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
<? include $tpl ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and `links.tpl.php` is the actual page template:

```
<h2><?=$pagetitle?></h2>
<ul>
<? foreach($DATA as $row): ?>
<li><a href="<?=$row['link']?>" target="_blank"><?=$row['name']?></a></li>
<? endforeach ?>
<ul>
```

Comment: +1 people misunderstand the concept of business logic and presentation logic and end up separating PHP and HTML which serves no purpose.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel thanks for your comments, what code should be use for separating business logic and presentation logic.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel thanks for great help. can you even help us with 1 mysql problem, we have columns id invoiceno. item1price item2price total, and how can we save total while inserting data to mysql, we can do it simple by using php... totalprice = $itemprice+$itemprice, is there any mysql function for this.  thanks again.

Comment: @seoppc do not save totals at all. Count it with select. That's the way databases work.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel thanks for reply, so we could use 'SELECT invoiceno., item1price, item2price, COUNT(item1price,ite2price) AS total from invoices'  right?

Comment: @seoppc on fact, you have to have 2 tables, one for invoices and another for items. then you will be able to select SUM(price) FROM invoice_items WJERE inv_id=invoices.id

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel yes we will use 2 different tables, but how to calculate total in case if we would like to know how much user xyz has paid, what would be the sql query for this?

Comment: @seoppc don't you think it would be better to ask a separate question instead of writing zillion comments?

Comment: @seoppc don't forget to include exact table structures, as it's impossible to write exact SQL query. Always provide complete data if you ask complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rewrite proven and existing functionality unless you have a very good reason. That markup is very similar to Smarty. Have a look at this : http://www.smarty.net/

If you want to rewrite it, then you might want to look at output buffering. Or you could create your own view framework where you set variables to a view object and it does all the code/scope management for you ala Zend, CakePHP